# How to time mutliple CSS events simultaneously?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css-transitions, timing

If anyone can get this simple example to work, I'd be super thankful!

```
var string = "cat";
var transitions = {0.3 , 0.2 , 0.6};
var timings = {0, 1.0, 1.5};
```

When I click a button, the clock starts at time = 0.

- At t = 0, '**c**' *begins* to appear.
- At t = 0.3 seconds, '**c**' has fully appeared.
- At t = 1.0 seconds, '**a**' *begins* to appear.
- At t = 1.2 seconds, '**c**' has fully appeared.
- At t = 1.5 seconds, '**t**' *begins* to appear.
- At t = 2.1 seconds, '**t**' has fully appeared.

After all this,  "cat" is displayed normally, as if it were typed straight into HTML.

Comment: Please make sure your javascript is valid. Also, what did you try before asking?

Comment: Please add any Javascript code you have tried so far, it will help everyone know where you're at

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I probably wouldn't use this without some additional cleanup, but this code works.

It was fun to write. And should meet your requirements.

```js
var transitions = [0.3 , 0.2 , 0.6];
var timings = [0, 1.0, 1.5];


function typeWrite(el, string) {
  return new Promise(
    function(resolve) {
      var i = 0;
      var l = string.length;
      
      function typeOne() {
        var chr = string[i];
        var span = document.createElement('span');
        span.innerHTML = chr;
        span.setAttribute('style', `transition: ${transitions[i]}s; opacity: 0;`); 
        el.appendChild(span);
        setTimeout(function() {span.className = 'typewriter-effect';},0);
        i++;
        if( i < l) {
          setTimeout(typeOne, timings[i]*1000);
        }
        else {
          resolve();
        }
      }
      
      typeOne();
    }
  )
}
      
typeWrite(document.querySelector('.typed-string'), 'cat').then(
  function() {
    console.log('Finished typing');
  }
);
```

```css
.typewriter-effect {
  opacity: 1 !important;
}
```

```html
<div class="typed-string"></div>
```

I normally hate using `!important` but this was a quick and simple way to allow the CSS class to override the `opacity` of the `style` attribute.

What I am doing is walking through the string and the two arrays you provided, then I am creating a new `<span>` for each letter and adding them into the DOM. Each new `<span>` indicates how long they take to fade in from `opacity:0` to `opacity:1`.

Then I call `setTimeout` to wait for the desired time before writing the next letter. This pattern continues until all letters have finished rendering. Then the routine resolves the promise so the calling code knows when the  writing routine is finished.

Answer (score 0):

You want to use steps in your css animation, along with keyframes (From this [tutorial](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/typewriter-effect/))

```
.typewriter-effect {
    animation: 
        typing 3.5s steps(40, end)
}

/* The typing effect */
@keyframes typing {
   from { width: 0 }
   to { width: 100% }
}
```

the way this works is your keyframes specify the effect, and the `steps` function determines how many parts it breaks down into.

Comment: Using just steps and keyframes seems to make each character appear with constant time and transition-duration, but sadly here they need to be different for each character, as specified by the arrays.

Comment: in that case you can manipulate keyframes to adjust to a different width at different %'s, rather than using the step function. I don't think you can use an array in this case, but you'll need to write down the different %'s for each letter.